# "The $H$-field is used because it includes the magnetization currents"

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

In this article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amp%C3%A8re%27s_circuital_law#Extending_the_original_law:_the_Amp%C3%A8re%E2%80%93Maxwell_equation

It says:

> "the $H$-field is used because it includes the magnetization currents, so $J_M$ does not appear explicitly"

What does this mean? We have defined $H$ as $H=1/\mu_0 B-M$. Does this tell us that $H$ does include magnetization currents?

And if it includes magnetisation currents, shouldn't $J_M$ be included explicitly? instead of excluded?

Comment: Bound currents can be calculated from $M$, so yes $H$ includes infromation about the bound currents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that in the equations

$$
\nabla \times \mathbf H = \mu_0 \mathbf j_f + \mu_0\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf D}{\partial t}
$$

$$
\oint_{\gamma} \mathbf H \cdot d\mathbf s = \mu_0 I_f + \mu_0\epsilon_0\frac{d\Phi_D}{dt}
$$

the current density $\mathbf j_f$ and current $I_f$ are only due to electric charge conduction current in medium or vacuum. So presence of magnetization current, if it is present, is taken into account by different terms - namely, in the term containing $\mathbf H$.